# Tomcat cannot locate jdbcmysql adapter with JRuby war

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, jruby, warbler

I'm trying to deploy a JRuby on Rails war into Tomcat6. For some reason, it cannot locate activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter. I'm running Rails 2.3.8, JRuby 1.5.5, JRuby-Rack 1.0.3. The gem is packaged with Bundler and I see it in the WEB-INF/gems/gems directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-19 20:07 WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter-0.9.2
```

Am I missing some environment variable or something that's causing Tomcat to not find the gem? It shows up in gem list, it's also in the appropriate directory.

My database.yml looks like the following:

```
production:
  adapter: jdbcmysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  username: foo
  password: somepassword
```

The traceback:

```
Nov 19, 2010 10:02:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: unable to create shared application instance
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (load error: jdbc_adapter/jdbc_adapter_internal -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/InvocationMethodFactory$DescriptorInfo)
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/spree-0.11.1/lib/spree/initializer.rb:90:in `run'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:13
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:44:in `load'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:44:in `load_environment'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:38:in `to_app'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:186:in `new'
 from <script>:2
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
 from <script>:2:in `new'
 from <script>:2

 at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:184)
 at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:59)
 at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:27)
 at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:40)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:145)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:769)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:902)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1258)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:177)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (load error: jdbc_adapter/jdbc_adapter_internal -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/InvocationMethodFactory$DescriptorInfo)
 at Kernel.raise(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438)
 at Rails::Initializer.initialize_database(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:141)
 at Rails::Initializer.process(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113)
 at #<Class:01x77277ffa>.run(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/spree-0.11.1/lib/spree/initializer.rb:90)
 at #<Class:01x251970e2>.run(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:13)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:44)
 at Kernel.load(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:44)
 at JRuby::Rack::RailsBooter::Rails2Environment.load_environment(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:38)
 at JRuby::Rack::RailsBooter::Rails2Environment.to_app(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:186)
 at #<Class:01x53371566>.new(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Kernel.instance_eval(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Kernel.instance_eval(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Rack::Builder.initialize(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).new(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
Nov 19, 2010 10:02:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error: application initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: unable to create shared application instance
 at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:39)
 at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:40)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:145)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:769)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:902)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1258)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
 at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:177)
Caused by: org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (load error: jdbc_adapter/jdbc_adapter_internal -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/InvocationMethodFactory$DescriptorInfo)
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/spree-0.11.1/lib/spree/initializer.rb:90:in `run'
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:13
 from /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:44:in `load'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:44:in `load_environment'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:38:in `to_app'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:186:in `new'
 from <script>:2
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
 from file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
 from <script>:2:in `new'
 from <script>:2

 at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:184)
 at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:59)
 at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:27)
 ... 32 more
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (load error: jdbc_adapter/jdbc_adapter_internal -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/InvocationMethodFactory$DescriptorInfo)
 at Kernel.raise(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55)
 at #<Class:01x3b96c67a>.establish_connection(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438)
 at Rails::Initializer.initialize_database(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:141)
 at Rails::Initializer.process(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113)
 at #<Class:01x77277ffa>.run(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/gems/gems/spree-0.11.1/lib/spree/initializer.rb:90)
 at #<Class:01x251970e2>.run(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:13)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:44)
 at Kernel.load(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:44)
 at JRuby::Rack::RailsBooter::Rails2Environment.load_environment(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:38)
 at JRuby::Rack::RailsBooter::Rails2Environment.to_app(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:186)
 at #<Class:01x53371566>.new(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Kernel.instance_eval(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Kernel.instance_eval(file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/fooproj/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.0.3.jar!/vendor/rack-1.2.1/rack/builder.rb:46)
 at Rack::Builder.initialize(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).new(<script>:2)
 at (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I was testing a small JRuby and Rails application and I never got database connections working using the **latest** versions of JRuby, Rails and Warbler.

After many, many iterations, this combination produced a WAR file which worked on Tomcat 5.5+:

- JRuby 1.3.1
- Rails 2.3.2
- warbler 0.9.13

Also, remember to uncomment the following line on *yourApp/config/warbler.conf* file:

```
config.gems += ["activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to [use MS SQL Server JDBC](http://www.ozmox.com/2010/11/20/use-ms-sql-server-with-rails-3-and-jruby/) with Tomcat.  It shouldn't be any different for MySQL.  I am not using the DB specific adapters though, but the generic JDBC adapter and then providing the actual JDBC driver in my /lib/java folder.

Just make sure warbler is packaging up the JDBC driver.  You should be able to inspect your .war file to make sure everything is there.  With Bundler you shouldn't need to specify config.gems += -- Warbler will grab all the gems in the Gemfile.lock.